# My cursor is not changing to the pic that I've chosen. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: css, image, cursor

I've been trying to get my cursor to change when I hover over the header. It won't. I've even changed the image size to 35px by 27px. How can I fix this?

```
header {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 190px;
    background-color: firebrick;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-left: black solid 1px;
    border-right: black solid 1px;
    cursor: url ('springDogwood.jpg'), auto;
}
```

Comment: Remove the space between `url` and your bracket.

Comment: Hey, thanks! It's working now.